# EPPLUS cannot delete worksheet >> "Part does not exist" (System.InvalidOperationException)

Tags: c#, epplus

I have build an excel workbook with several worksheets as a reporting template.
The task is done by creating a new excelpackage from the designed xlsx file and fill it up with data.
The template xlsx containing charts and data worksheets.

```
var packageReport = new ExcelPackage();
packageReport.Load(new memoryStream(Properties.Resources.Reporting_Template));
packageReport.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(3) // not working >> Exception
packageReport.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(packageReport.Workbook.Worksheets["Name"]) // not working >> Exception

var ws = packageReport.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOfDefault(w => w.Name == "Name");
packageReport.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(ws); // Exception
```

Also have tried to select the worksheet in a object var before, with also no luck ... Cannot delete any of my newly created worksheets ... :(

Any idea is welcome ...
Thx. Dudes.

---

Current EPPlus.dll (Version: 4.0.5.0, Runtime Version: v2.0.50727)

### Addition:

Also tried to use the template constructor function to generate a copy of the excel stored as a memorystream object with no luck.

Comment: What is the exception exactly?  Does Worksheets contain anything when you debug? Did you try using the ExcelPackage overload that takes an template file as an input?  So something like `using (pck= new ExcelPackage(newFile, templateFile))`.  You can see how it works from the source code:  http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelPackage.cs

Comment: The Exception is like: “Part does not exist” (System.InvalidOperationException). 
But nice, will have a look at the above and will be report back. Thank you dude.

Comment: Hi there, I'm currently working with a stream in memory, so i'm using: public ExcelPackage(Stream newStream, Stream templateStream). But with no luck ... :(

Comment: after 5 years the problem persists on the most recent version....., might aswell try some other lib